# Validation Regular Expression in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, regex

In an HTML DOC I reported for a textbox the following validation code:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revPhone" runat="server" 
            CssClass="validator" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Phone number" 
            ValidationExpression="((\(\d{3}\) ?)|(\d{3}-))?\d{3}-\d{4}?|(\d{6.9})?" 
            ControlToValidate="txtPhone" >Use this format: 999-999-9999 or 999999 0r 999999999
 </asp:RegularExpressionValidator><br />
```

I would like to understand if this regular expression:

```
ValidationExpression="((\(\d{3}\) ?)|(\d{3}-))?\d{3}-\d{4}?|(\d{6.9})?"
```

is correct to be able to enter one of the following values:

234-456-7890
234567
234567890

Because it returns me the error message if I enter:
234567890

Comment: Thank you
I replaced the expression with the one you suggested:

    ValidationExpression="(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})|\d{6,9}"

 but the problem remains.

Comment: The code:

    ValidationExpression="((\(\d{3}\) ?)|(\d{3}-))?\d{3}-\d{4}?"

works properly but only if I enter 999-999-9999
Thank you

Comment: colinD: Yes I saw it and used it. But it doesn't work. I don't know what to say. Thank you

Comment: colinD: I'm sorry I don't speak well in English

Answer (score 1):

The start and end of the string delimiters are missing, which is why I thing the regex is not working.

`^` is the start of the string, `$` the end of it.

This should work:

```
^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$|^\d{6}$|^\d{9}$
```

Which means:

```
^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$ --> start, then 3 groups of digits with a '-' in the middle, then end
| --> or
^\d{6}$ --> start then 6 digits then end
| --> or
^\d{6}$ --> start then 9 digits then end
```

---

You can see it here: https://regex101.com/r/HgI3R5/2

Good website to test regex, includes reference of the tokens you can use and an explanation of the regex you're building.